# Blocking write operations within Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring

Are write specific operations within Hibernate blocking? I mean, if I execute:

```
session.save(data);
```

from a method which is annotated as @Transactional, is it guaranteed that every

```
session.get(id);
```

call, coming from a different thread, executed immediately after this line, will return proper data (not null)?

Answer (score 1):

The result that you get depends on the transaction isolation level. Spring allows the following isolation levels:

> DEFAULT
>             Use the default isolation level of the underlying datastore.
>
> READ_COMMITTED
>             A constant indicating that dirty reads are prevented; non-repeatable reads and phantom reads can occur.
>
> READ_UNCOMMITTED
>             A constant indicating that dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads can occur.
>
> REPEATABLE_READ
>             A constant indicating that dirty reads and non-repeatable reads are prevented; phantom reads can occur.
>
> SERIALIZABLE
>             A constant indicating that dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads are prevented.

Calling the save() (or flush()) doesn't guarantee that the transaction is committed. In the case when your transaction(where the save() is called) commits before the get() is called, you will ALWAYS get the correct result in the new thread. However, if the transaction is not committed, whether you get the correct result or not depends on the transaction isolation level. You will get the correct result in the isolation levels that allow "Dirty Reads".

Comment: How can I be sure that this happens? Should I try to commit the transactions manually? Or maybe I can set a flag, where I declare the method as TRANSACTIONAL?

Comment: Why exactly do you want this behavior? If you want to make sure that this happens, you can make the method in which you call the get() transactional with the isolation level as READ_UNCOMMITTED. You might get some dirty reads though.

Answer (score 0):

Write operations are not block unless you use pessimistic locking explicitly. In a transaction, what happens is the un-committed will not be visible to anybody outside this transaction (assuming the default isolation level READ_COMMITTED). As you mentioned `save()` and `get()` are running in different threads and hence different transactions, it all depends upon the fact the at time of get() whether the save() was committed or not.